# Distinguish between filled polygon and boundary

Tags: polygon-creation, polygonize, shape-area

[image]

[image]

I am trying to convert the raster images to vector and get the inner filled polygon. But the filled polygon and its boundary are wrongly detected for some cases. Below is the code where I tried to distinguish using area. How to distinguish them?

```
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = drv.Open('test/raster_to_vector.shp', 1)

#print (dataSource)

layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

list1=[]

list2=[]

for feature in layer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()

    dn1 = feature.GetField('DN')

    area = geom.GetArea()

    if (area > 10 and area < 3000):

        list1.append(dn1)

        list2.append(area)

    else:

        layer.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())
```